# How do I remote into Windows Phone 8 using WinRT?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10

I found this [link (Project My Screen).](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42536)

However, I really want to control a Windows Phone from another Windows 8 or Windows 10 device.

Can I do this?

If not then how can I?

Comment: I get down-voted for asking an API related question?

Answer (score 1):

There are no APIs that allow for this.  WinRT doesn't have them, and it would require very low-level access to make this happen.